# Raspberry can't access /dev/mem

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I have installed Raspbian on my Raspberry and added in:

1. /etc/rc.local:

   ```
    chown /dev/ttyUSB0 #to allow current user to use 3G modem
   ```
2. /etc/sudoers:

   ```
    raspbian ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```
3. And for autologin:

   ```
    1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --autologin raspbian --noclear 38400 tty1
   ```

Before I can use GPIO from Python to write to GPIO pins.

Now when I try to run with sudo my Python script I receive an exception where is write that I can't access /dev/mem

I tried to add "raspbian" user to group "kmem" but don't works.

I tried to remove autologin and sudo without password, but also don't works.

I tried with WiringPi from C, and with WiringPi works.

Please help me to find a solution to use GPIO from python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

I forgot about:

```
  GPIO.setup(<PIN>, <MODE>)
```

And without this Python throws and exception where write to try to run code with root.