# No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm a newbie!

I have python files code to turn on the light:
i tried  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469825/raspberry-cant-access-dev-mem?rq=1)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389013/raspberry-pi-python-pwm-runtimeerror-no-access-to-dev-mem?rq=1) and here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469825/raspberry-cant-access-dev-mem) on forum
i chmod pi for /dev , adduser group
**file 1**

```
print "================================"
    print "ROBOT: DANG MO QUAT"
    print "================================"
os.system("aplay -D hw:1,0 /home/pi/jasper/static/audio/dangmoquat.wav")
minh.main(['-p',pin,'on'])
```

**file 2** access GPIO:

```
def GPIO_SETMODE(pin):
    if int(pin) in GPIOs:
#   GPIO.cleanup()
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use BOARD pin numbering
        GPIO.setup(int(pin), GPIO.OUT)
    return True
    else:
    return False 


def main(argv):
       type = ''   
       try:
          opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"b:p:h:s:r",['input=', 'params=', 'help'])
       except getopt.GetoptError:
          print 'Wrong command'
          sys.exit(2)
       print opts,args

       for opt, arg in opts:
          #...........doing something here....................#
       elif opt in ("-p", "--power"):
     input = arg
         if GPIO_SETMODE(input):#------------> errror occurs here#
                if args[0] == 'on':
                        Power(int(input), True)
                elif args[0] == 'off':
                        Power(int(input), False)
                else:
                        print 'Please choose on or off'
```

Error occurs here.

"No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!"
i have try  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469825/raspberry-cant-access-dev-mem?rq=1)

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389013/raspberry-pi-python-pwm-runtimeerror-no-access-to-dev-mem?rq=1) and here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469825/raspberry-cant-access-dev-mem) on forum

and google. I was awaked until dawn. I have chmod 777 pi dev -R 
What can i do know?
Please help me.

Comment: perhaps this question is better for the [raspi stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ^^
What is difference from 2 forum? 

^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only access to /dev can be privileged for access, also the device itself will probably be protected.

You should do an ls -l /dev and check the I/O device you are trying to access. Once you see the group, try adding yourself to that group:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG <iogroup> user
```

After that, you probably need to log out and in again for the group to be added.

Else you could change the permission to 777 (of the *device*), but changing the group is more correct.